# Scala Error on List's Unzip method

Tags: scala

I have a List of tuples. Each element of the tuple is of type MyClass:

```
case class MyClass(metrics: List[MyOtherClass], tags: Set[String])
```

I want to call the unzip method to get a tuple of Lists. I am getting the following error messages:[image: Error]

I know the method definition is:`def unzip[A1, A2](implicit asPair: (A) ⇒ (A1, A2)): (List[A1], List[A2])`

But when I call I unzip method on a List[(Int,Int)] the compiler does not ask me to include the asPair parameter.

**What am I missing here?**

Comment: are you sure that all elements of your list are tuples with 2 elements?

Comment: Can you provide an example list that does not work with `unzip`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the compiler does not ask me to include the asPair parameter

That's because it's `implicit`. Please read up about implicit parameters in Scala.

> I have a List of tuples. Each element of the tuple is of type MyClass

The error message tells you that what you actually have is `List[Product with Serializable]`. Most common reason is that it's a list of unrelated case classes/objects; based on the quoted sentence, it may be tuples with different number of elements, but you could also accidentally have e.g. a `Some` in there. `unzip` only works on lists of pairs, not arbitrary tuples.

Answer (score 0):

I lack enough rep to comment, but if you could post an example with some code where this doesn't work, that would be quite helpful.

I've put together a simple example, and unzip works as expected.

```
object Test {
  case class MyClass(metrics: List[MyOtherClass], tags: Set[String])
  case class MyOtherClass(thing: Int)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val a = List.fill(2)(
      (
        MyClass(List(MyOtherClass(1)), Set("foo")),
        MyClass(List(MyOtherClass(2)), Set("bar"))
      )
    )
    println(a.unzip)
  }
}
```

Which outputs

```
(List(MyClass(List(MyOtherClass(1)),Set(foo)), MyClass(List(MyOtherClass(1)),Set(foo))),List(MyClass(List(MyOtherClass(2)),Set(bar)), MyClass(List(MyOtherClass(2)),Set(bar))))
```